# different image widths in vGrid

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using [vGrid](https://github.com/xlune/jQuery-vGrid-Plugin), a masonry-like plugin, to display my images. I'm trying to display them such that random images will be bigger than the rest, and I came upon this answer ([Jquery Isotope plugin: Generating random sized images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814738/jquery-isotope-plugin-generating-random-sized-images)) but it doesn't seem to work on my site? There were no visible changes.

The added codes:

```
.frontpageimagehigh {
    height: 420px !important;
    width: 300px !important;}
```

And:

```
<script>$('#grid-content .figure:nth-child(2)').find('.mainGallery .image').addClass('frontpageimagehigh');</script>
```

Are there any other methods of getting random (i'm currently just starting out on the second image first) images to have different sizes with vGrid? Thank you!

If needed, this is [my site](http://www.victoriayww.portfoliobox.me/).

Comment: Some console errors? Are you sure of the selectors ? how looks your html ? have you tried calling that change on some anonymus function or `document.ready`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is with your selectors:

You are searching for the second child with class `figure` inside a container with id `grid-content`:

```
#grid-content .figure:nth-child(2)
```

That works fine but with this:

```
find('.mainGallery .image')
```

You are searching inside the `figure` element another with class `mainGallery`, that is not correct mainGallery is the same as the id grid-content then you can't find that element inside `figure` change it to:

```
find('.openLightBox .image')
```

Where `openLightBox` is the `a` tag that contains `.image`.

Call it like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#grid-content .figure:nth-child(2)').find('.openLightBox .image').addClass('frontpageimagehigh')
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Changed it accordingly to this `<script>$('#grid-content .figure:nth-child(2)').find('.openLightBox .image').addClass('frontpageimagehigh');</script>` but still no change?

Comment: Have you changed that on your site so I can check?

Comment: My friend call that on the function with $(document).ready check the edit @user2446412

Comment: Ah sorry for that silly mistake! It works now! Though is there a way to adjust the column with the image? I'm actually trying to recreate the effect in [this theme](https://github.com/corygibbons/yuki).

Comment: That site works with masonry @user2446412 but if you want make another question I think this is solved now :) . don't forget to check the answer

Comment: I appreciate all the help! :) Yep I've made another question.